# Extract specific links with specific class in href using Python and Requests-html

Tags: python

I wrote a code to extract all links from a webpage, but I'd like to extract only links with a specific class attribute inside my  tags.

I am going to explain it better with an example.

This is the html on the webpage:

```
    <tr><td class="h-text-left"><a href="/football/algeria/ligue-1/aso-chlef-cr-belouizdad/bNvFStWr/" class="in-match"><span>ASO Chlef</span> - <span>CR Belouizdad</span></a></td><td class="h-text-center"><a href="/football/algeria/ligue-1/aso-chlef-cr-belouizdad/bNvFStWr/">0:0</a></td><td class="table-main__odds" data-oid="6r9u7xv464x0xicel6" data-odd="3.24"></td><td class="table-main__odds colored" data-oid="6r9u7xv498x0x0"><span><span><span data-odd="2.89"></span></span></span></td><td class="table-main__odds" data-oid="6r9u7xv464x0xicel7" data-odd="2.30"></td><td class="h-text-right h-text-no-wrap">19.01.</td></tr>
<tr><td class="h-text-left"><a href="/football/algeria/ligue-1/constantine-es-ben-aknoun/lCXRPvG1/" class="in-match"><span>Constantine</span> - <span>Ben Aknoun</span></a></td><td class="h-text-center"><a href="/football/algeria/ligue-1/constantine-es-ben-aknoun/lCXRPvG1/">1:1</a></td><td class="table-main__odds" data-oid="6r9uaxv464x0xicelc" data-odd="1.19"></td><td class="table-main__odds colored" data-oid="6r9uaxv498x0x0"><span><span><span data-odd="5.57"></span></span></span></td><td class="table-main__odds" data-oid="6r9uaxv464x0xiceld" data-odd="14.73"></td><td class="h-text-right h-text-no-wrap">19.01.</td></tr>
<tr><td class="h-text-left"><a href="/football/algeria/ligue-1/el-bayadh-oran/fkYNQK0e/" class="in-match"><span>El Bayadh</span> - <span><strong>Oran</strong></span></a></td><td class="h-text-center"><a href="/football/algeria/ligue-1/el-bayadh-oran/fkYNQK0e/">0:1</a></td><td class="table-main__odds" data-oid="6r9u9xv464x0xicela" data-odd="1.64"></td><td class="table-main__odds" data-oid="6r9u9xv498x0x0" data-odd="3.30"></td><td class="table-main__odds colored" data-oid="6r9u9xv464x0xicelb"><span><span><span data-odd="5.76"></span></span></span></td><td class="h-text-right h-text-no-wrap">19.01.</td></tr>
```

This is my code:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession 

matchlink = 'https://www.betexplorer.com/football/algeria/ligue-1/results/'
 
session = HTMLSession()
 
r = session.get(matchlink)


links = r.html.links

for link in links:
    matchlinks = link
 
    session = HTMLSession()
 
    r = session.get('https://www.betexplorer.com' + matchlinks)
    r.html.render()
    print(link)
```

This code works for all links, but, I'd like to extract only  links with class="in-match".

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can specify a simple CSS selector criteria in your links selector. Something like this:

```py
links = r.html.find('a.in-match')

for link in links:
    match_link = link.attrs['href']
    print(match_link)
```

This selects all `anchor tags` with the class `in-match`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but I got an error like "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "Element") to str"

Comment: Sorry for the oversight. After selecting the links, you need to extract the href attribute from the link. I have updated the answer above.